Unable to deploy R tutorials built using learnr to Shiny.io
I am having issues deploying R tutorials developed using the learnr package. I have tried a test deploy using the basic tutorial that is generated from the interactive tutorial template in RStudio, but I keep getting an authorization error. I don't believe that there are any issues with my connection to my Shiny publishing account as I frequently update and deploy shiny apps without any issues. I have also tried generating new keys multiple times but the problem persists.
Here's the error:
----- Deployment error -----
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1446984232 child_task_status=failed: Error building image: Error fetching learnr (0.11.5.9000) source. Error accessing GitHub repository rstudio/learnr. HTTP 401: Unauthorized
 
----- Error stack trace -----

4: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/code/test2", 
       appFileManifest = "/var/folders/nm/nm2q6pg520bgts_fpg2f2rl40000gp/T/1101-6ba4-a50f-0a65", 
       appPrimaryDoc = "test2.Rmd", appSourceDoc = "~/code/test2/test2.Rmd", 
    ...

3: client$waitForTask(taskId, quiet)

2: stop(status$error, call. = FALSE)

1: (function (e) 
   {
       cat("----- Deployment error -----\n")
    ...

Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1446984232 child_task_status=failed: Error building image: Error fetching learnr (0.11.5.9000) source. Error accessing GitHub repository rstudio/learnr. HTTP 401: Unauthorized
Execution halted


UPDATE: I tried publishing the example tutorial to my shiny.io account using another machine and everything worked without error, so it seems the problem is with my local machine, but as of yet I have not been able to find the cause.

This solution was the answer for me:
https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/197#issuecomment-327822338

In the shinyapps.io dashboard, disable your Github token that allows access to private repositories, and then re-enable it. If that token becomes invalid, then all interactions with Github repos, public and private, will fail.


